# Remove number from url. RewriteRule

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a blog with a list of files. They have a number, a dash and the name of the post. I try to remove the number and the dash.

Of course, the number (in the example "1") and the name of the post, will be different in each case.

For example:

Can I redirect?
from:  blog/name-of-the-post
to: blog/1-name-of-the-post

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/(\D*)$ /blog\/\d{1,3}-$1
```

Comment: Is the number a fixed number for all files?

Comment: The number 1 in the example is the number of the post. So, there will be as many numbers as posts

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.

If you want redirect

from :

- example.com/blog/numbers-name-of-the-post

to

- example.com/blog/name-of-the-post

try :

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+-)/(.+)$ /blog/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

or If you want redirect

from :

- example.com/blog/name-of-the-post

to

- example.com/blog/numbers-name-of-the-post

try :

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ /blog/1/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: The number 1 is just an example. Could be any number of 3 digits. I have url with a number (any number) and the name of the post (any name). I want to remove the number. So in .htaccess I should redirect from the clean address without the number to the real file with a number and the name of the post